Parametricity and data kinds
I am wondering about the MonoMaybe type family from the monad-validation Haskell library written by Alexis King. Its definition is as follows (ignoring strictness):
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}
data MonoMaybeS = SMaybe | SJust

data MonoMaybe (s :: MonoMaybeS) a where
  MNothing :: MonoMaybe 'SMaybe a
  MJust :: forall s a. a -> MonoMaybe s a

This is analogous to Maybe, but the type forall s. MonoMaybe s A -> MonoMaybe s B enforces the invariant that the function is "monotonically increasing", in that it can only output MNothing when given MNothing, by parametricity. However, usual parametricity allows one to reason about universal quantification on the universe, while here s has type MonoMaybeS (which in GHC Haskell is "promoted" to the type level by the DataKinds extension).
Questions: how can we analyse the above? Is there a type theory in which one can define an indexed type family like above and prove an equivalence between $\forall s. \text{MonoMaybe}\ s\ A \to \text{MonoMaybe}\ s\ B$ and the subtype of $\text{Maybe}\ A \to \text{Maybe}\ B$ on the monotonically increasing functions? Can e.g. parametric cubical type theory à la Cavallo & Harper do this?
I have the following geometric intuition for the total space of $\lambda s. \text{MonoMaybe}\ s\ A$:

The indexing type $\text{MonoMaybeS}$ behaves as a sort of abstract interval (in particular one is not able to case split on it) which seems like it might have to do with bridge types.

By forall s. MonoMaybe s a -> MonoMaybe s b do you mean forall a b s. MonoMaybe s a -> MonoMaybe s b?  Surely when you restrict to fixed and inhabited b it is easy to output whatever you like.  Or maybe you mean forall a b s. (a -> b) -> MonoMaybe s a -> MonoMaybe s b?

No, a and b are arbitrary types here. The const MNothing function does not type-check at that type.

Then your type is the same as forall a b s. MonoMaybe s a -> MonoMaybe s b, right?  If this is the case, why do you write forall s but not forall a b?  (Is this Haskell imposing dumb restrictions on dependent types?)

No! I am considering the type forall s. MonoMaybe s A -> MonoMaybe s B for given types A and B. Take A = Bool and B = Bool if you like.

I'm not sure there's any ready made system for precisely this (at least, I haven't seen/understood it yet). There's lots of adjacent work, though.
Cavallo & Harper isn't it, because it's modelling something like the normal parametricity situation, where because you don't have type-case, $Π$ types over the universe have to be uniform with respect to discrete results. But the Haskell example is the sort of scenario where you have two different $Π$ types. One is the normal $Π$ (which yields Haskell functions) and the other is a parametric $Π$ (Haskell $∀$) that is parametric because of computational irrelevance, regardless of what you're quantifying over.
So, to model this situation, I think you need something more like Nuyts, Vezossi & Devriese, which has a separate parametric $Π$. However, I think the problem with this is that each type is equipped with a particular notion of bridge, and the ones for data types like MonoMaybeS are just discrete, so being 'parametric' in them is still not any different than the normal $Π$.
But, you could probably say that MonoMaybeS is different from similar types described in teh paper in that its bridges match what happens in Haskell. I think that means you want the type to be bridge indiscrete (all values are related). Or maybe just say that things like (small) data types are bridge indiscrete instead of discrete to model the Haskell situation.
There is also work on modelling reasons underlying this sort of parametricity. For instance, Nathan Mishra-Linger's thesis has a system with computational irrelevance (which is not quite the same as e.g. Agda's irrelevance), involving two varieties of $Π$. But I don't believe it includes the parametricity aspects induced by irrelevance (at the time internal parametricity was an open question, I think). The only extra theorems you get are the simple ones that result from erasing irrelevant things.
Perhaps Sterling and Harper's Logical Relations as Types can handle all this. I cannot tell.

If you just want to avoid having a case on MonoMaybeS, you should be able to parametrize over it and use any version of parametricity that handles dependent types.  In Coq, the type I'm suggesting would be using the definition
Inductive MonoMaybe (MonoMaybeS : Type) (SMaybe : MonoMaybeS) (SJust : MonoMaybeS) : MonoMaybeS -> Type -> Type :=
| MNothing : forall a, MonoMaybe MonoMaybeS SMaybe SJust SMaybe a
| MJust : forall s a, a -> MonoMaybe MonoMaybeS SMaybe SJust s a
.

and the type
forall MonoMaybeS SMaybe SJust a b s, MonoMaybe MonoMaybeS SMaybe SJust s a -> MonoMaybe MonoMaybeS SMaybe SJust s b

The version given in the question should already guarantee monotonicity. The question is "How do we formally prove that the type in the question guarantees monotonicity?"

Right, abstracting over the type is something I thought about, but then my question is: "is there a version of parametricity that handles dependent types?". I guess the work by Nuyts, Vezzosi and Devriese would probably suffice.

(I had in mind something more akin to defining a concrete, closed type family that looks like MonoMaybe, maybe as something like a higher inductive type family but with bridges instead of paths; but to be fair, my question was open-ended.)
